# Does anybody know how to share the google colab document so people can run the notebook but cannot see the actual code?

Tags: data-visualization, computer-science, google-colaboratory, software-distribution

I am trying to share the google colab document (that contains my data-visualization project) with friends so they can run the code but not actually see the code, because I don't want them to copy the code. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think Colab is designed with this in mind. While you could have a separate python file in your drive that the code accesses with something like pydrive, for it to either import a function or result, and then display that result, that's no different in consequence to just having the output displayed in a notebook cell or picture format. The real question here is why showing the output alone is insufficient. Why do you need to allow your friends to 'run the code'? What do you gain from having them hit shift+enter on a cell to display an output instead of just showing them the output.

Comment: Because I am getting real time COVID data.